# How to call base class function from vector of derived class with templates without virtual functions in base class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, derived-class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
class IModule {};

template<typename T>
class Base : public IModule{
    public:
    T BaseT;
    void BaseFoo () {};
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class ABase : public Base<T> {
    public:
    U ABaseU;
    void ABaseFoo() {};
};

template<typename T, typename V>
class BBase : public Base<T> {
    public:
    V BBaseV;
    void BBaseFoo() {};
};

class ADerived : public ABase<int, std::string> {
    public:
    void ADerivedFoo () {};
};


class BDerived : public BBase<double, double> {};


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IModule>> allobjs;

    std::unique_ptr<ADerived> ADerivedInstance = std::make_unique<ADerived>();
    allobjs.push_back(std::move(ADerivedInstance));

    std::unique_ptr<BDerived> BDerivedInstance = std::make_unique<BDerived>();
    allobjs.push_back(std::move(BDerivedInstance));

    std::cout << "Size: " << allobjs.size() << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < allobjs.size(); i++)
    {
        allobjs[i]->BaseFoo(); // error: ‘class IModule’ has no member named ‘BaseFoo’
        allobjs[i]->ABaseFoo(); // error: ‘class IModule’ has no member named ‘ABaseFoo’
        allobjs[i]->ADerivedFoo(); // error: ‘class IModule’ has no member named ‘ADerivedFoo’
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

I run into this error -
`error: ‘class IModule’ has no member named`

(For `ABaseFoo`, I have an internal method to call the function only if it is of ABase type. But in `main() for loop` I do not know the templates.)

Is such a thing possible with this design *without* adding `virtual` functions of all derived classes in `IModule`?
The following code with IModule compiles -

```
class IModule {
    public:
    virtual void BaseFoo() = 0;
    virtual void ABaseFoo(){};
    virtual void BBaseFoo(){};
    virtual void ADerivedFoo(){};
};
```

I want to avoid above virtual functions in base class.

If not, what could I possibly do in this case where I have derived classes with different templates?

Comment: The whole point of the interface design is to expose all relevant functionality in the interface. If for whatever reason this is not suitable, you should come up with a different solution. As to answer the question: yes, there are ways to call derived class functions but they are far worse than using virtual methods; like performing dynamic cast and then using the member function.

Comment: All the approaches I know of that permit you to implement this without virtual functions basically come down to a less maintainable and probably less performant version switching functionality based on the real type of the object and you're probably better of using virtual functions. Not sure what you're trying to improve here, but if the preformance penalty by using virtual functions is significant in your case and you're trying to remove that, in some scenarios you'd simply create different vectors for every element type and then iterate through them one after the other...

Comment: If you have different types with different methods then they go in different containers (aka one `vector<unique_ptr<ADerived>>` and one `vector<unique_ptr<BDerived>>`)

Comment: why do you want to avoid virtual functions?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number no performance concerns actually, just that some functions are specific to derived classes and didn't make semantic sense to us in the base class.

Comment: That's a rather complex setup -- two inheritance chains, three levels of inheritance, plus templates at most of the levels. Could you answer your question if you changed the class templates to actual classes? Could you answer your question if you dropped to two, or even one, level of inheritance? (I grant that having two chains is somewhat fundamental to the question being asked.) If you could answer if given these simplifications, please add that to the question (as a starting point). If there is a simplification for which you could not answer, please use it to simplify your question.